# Java storing method into arraylist

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

Currently I am storing method of page into array. But I want to store these method into arraylist but not sure what is wrong with it.

```
WizardPage[] pages={pageone(), pagetwo(), pagethree()};
```

versus

```
List<WizardPage> pageStore = new ArrayList<WizardPage>();

pageStore.add(pageone());
pageStore.add(pagetwo());
pageStore.add(pagethree());

public WizardPage pageone() {

            WizardPage pageone = new WizardPage("one","page 1");

            Do something~

           return pageone;

       }

public WizardPage pagetwo() {

            WizardPage pageone = new WizardPage("two","page 2");

            Do something~

           return pagetwo;

       }

public WizardPage pagethree() {

            WizardPage pageone = new WizardPage("three","page 3");

            Do something~

           return pagethree;

       }
```

Comment: You aren't storing a method, you are storing the return value.

Comment: You're not *actually* storing the methods in the ArrayList, as methods aren't "first class" in Java.  Instead you're storing the return value of those methods.

Comment: that title scared me !!!

Comment: @GV Hey, I _did_ store java.lang.reflect.Method into ArrayLists a couple of times... That is not a fairy tale though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an different note than the fact that you aren't actually storing the methods, but their return types, you've got this

```
List<WizardPage> pageStore = new ArrayList<WizardPage>();

pageStore.add(pageone());
pageStore.add(pagetwo());
pageStore.add(pagethree());
```

Since all the methods `pageX()` are all instance methods, you need an instance to call them on. Assuming the class those methods appear in is called `WizardBook`, you would need something like

```
WizardBook book = new WizardBook();
List<WizardPage> pageStore = new ArrayList<WizardPage>();

pageStore.add(book.pageone());
pageStore.add(book.pagetwo());
pageStore.add(book.pagethree());
```

Or make the methods `static`.

...unless of course you are running it within an instance member context.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to store the methods instead of their return values then

instead of

```
List<WizardPage> pageStore = new ArrayList<WizardPage>();
pageStore.add(pageone());
pageStore.add(pagetwo());
pageStore.add(pagethree());
```

try

```
List<Method> pageStore = new ArrayList<Method>();
try {
    pageStore.add(this.getClass().getMethod("pageone"));
    pageStore.add(this.getClass().getMethod("pagetwo"));
    pageStore.add(this.getClass().getMethod("pagethree"));
} catch ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP was after, but it definitely works. The "Method" object stored here is not the method itself. It is an object that provides information about the method :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, methods are not objects. You can't store methods in an array or ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Fist point to say **You cannot store a method, you can only store its return value**.

I don't see any problem in storing the returned values into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Store an array of objects. Objects have methods, so you can then access (either call or for special purposes use reflection) the methods.

What you are trying to do is unclear, but it looks as though you want 3 objects of class `WizardPage`, with some String fields, and which perhaps has a method like `void doPageUpdateStuff()`. On the other hand, maybe all the work can be done in the constructor.